# VSTO C# Word Add-In, I can't figure out how to get a wild card find and replace to not replace text outside of a table

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am trying to ignore text outside of a table and not have it commented or replaced and only find and replace if inside a table.  The correct behavior should be to replace the word [Pp]ounds to lbs. if it is in a table and comment it, if [Pp]ounds is outside of a table it should not be commented or replaced.

Here is the state of the document before I click a button that will run my function.

[image]

Here is the state after.  It correctly changes the first instanace of Pounds and Comments it, then the second word Pounds is changed(incorrectly) but it correctly ommits the comment.  Then incorrectly it doesn't even get to the 3rd instance of the word Pounds and it should have replaced it to lbs. and commented it.
[image]

```
wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Execute(MatchWildcards: true, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);//Just set the argument MatchWildcards here!! like you wrote in this line : wordRange.Find.Execute(FindText: wildCardText, MatchCase: false, MatchWildcards: true);
            while (wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Found && (bool)wordRangeFindReplace.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable))
```

I thought Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable would do it.
I think the Find.Execute Method is changing it before wdWithInTable can check if it's in a table, and now I also don't know why it's not moving to the second table and the 3rd or 4th instances of the word Pounds.

I can't tell in the debugger the exact moment when Pounds is changing to lbs.
I have also tried

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTables; i++)
            {
                if (wordRangeFindReplace.Start >= document.Tables[i].Range.Start)
                {*/
```

and I get similar results.

Here is the full code.
This is the Code that get's called in a click event handler.

```
Rule pounds = new Rule("Pounds", "Pounds shouldn't be spelled out", RuleType.WildCardFindAndReplaceInTable);

pounds.WildCardFindAndReplaceInTable("[Pp]ounds", "lbs.", "Abbreviate units of weight in tables (for example, lbs. and oz.). (Rule 49)");
```

and here is the method WildCardFindAndReplaceInTable

```
public void WildCardFindAndReplaceInTable(string textToFind, string replacementText, string commentMessage)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.UndoRecord ur = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.UndoRecord;
        ur.StartCustomRecord("FindReplaceAndCommentWithWildCards");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wordRangeFindReplace = null;
        Word.Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        wordRangeFindReplace = document.Content;
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.ClearFormatting();
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.ClearAllFuzzyOptions();
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.IgnoreSpace = true;
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.MatchCase = false;
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Text = textToFind;

        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Replacement.Text = replacementText;
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Forward = true;
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;

        //don't forget the Replace argument
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Execute(MatchWildcards: true, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);//Just set the argument MatchWildcards here!! like you wrote in this line : wordRange.Find.Execute(FindText: wildCardText, MatchCase: false, MatchWildcards: true);
        while (wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Found && (bool)wordRangeFindReplace.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable))
        {
            object commentText = "[REPLACED] " + commentMessage + " -CME";
            Word.Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(wordRangeFindReplace.Start, wordRangeFindReplace.End);
            //rng.Text = replacementText;//This is wrong!! refer to above
            document.Comments.Add(rng, ref commentText);
            wordRangeFindReplace.Find.ClearFormatting();

            // Next Find
            //don't forget to reset the range wordRange
            wordRangeFindReplace.SetRange(wordRangeFindReplace.End, wordRangeFindReplace.Document.Content.End);

            //wordRange.Find.Execute(FindText: wildCardText, MatchCase: false, MatchWildcards: true);
            wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Execute(MatchWildcards: true, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
        }

        ur.EndCustomRecord();

    }
```

I just don't know what's going on here, and what I'm doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your comments (`//rng.Text = replacementText;//This is wrong!! refer to above`) suggests that you may have been doing the right thing earlier The main problems are that when you do

```
wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Execute(MatchWildcards: true, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
```

Word will do the replacement immediately, i.e. before you have actually checked whether the found text is in a table or not.

So you need to change both the .Execute statementsthat so it just does this:

```
wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Execute(MatchWildcards: true, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceNone);
```

(Or I think you can omit the second parameter altogether)

So then you need to do the replacement when you find the text in a table. But, as things stand, the loop terminates either if you don't find the text or if the text is not in a table. So if you have one instance of the Find text before any tables, your code won't look for any more.

So IMO you need something more like this. [I am actually working with a VBA translation right now so may have got the C# syntax wrong. Also, it means I haven't actually tested the .Information test.]

```
    while (wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Found)
    { 
        if ((bool)wordRangeFindReplace.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable))
        {
            // actually do the replacement
            wordRangeFindReplace.Text = replacementText;
            object commentText = "[REPLACED] " + commentMessage + " -CME";
            // you don't need to work so hard to create the comment!
            wordRangeFindReplace.Comments.Add(wordRangeFindReplace, ref commentText);            
        }
        // then set up the next Find regardless of whether you were in a table or not.
        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.ClearFormatting();

        // Next Find
        //don't forget to reset the range wordRange
        wordRangeFindReplace.SetRange(wordRangeFindReplace.End, wordRangeFindReplace.Document.Content.End);

        wordRangeFindReplace.Find.Execute(MatchWildcards: true, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceNone);
    }
```

Starting from there, I suggest you rethink the loop logic from scratch as it might be possible to simplify it, and there are a few other lines you don't need if you're not doing "find with replace"

Comment: It worked, and like you said you can omit Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceNone.  Thanks a bunch!